# How do I "noindex" a text (.txt) file?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, web-crawlers, robots.txt, noindex

I have a directory full of .txt files that are used as part of a larger javascript application. The text files are not inteded to be directly accessed, and are used as includes on separate pages as part of the application functionality).

So.. I added the directory to my robots.txt file because I don't want the files to show up independently in search results.

However, robots.txt simply makes the .txt files inaccessible to robots. It doesn't actually make the .txt files un-indexable.

What I really want to do is "noindex" the .txt files.  But .txt files aren't like .html files.. a noindex meta tag will be visible in the text.

So how does one "noindex" a file that's raw text without corrupting the text with a tag?

Is there some other way to noindex a text file, externally? Or noindex the overall directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is the same as for [X-Robots noindex a folder of PDFs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77975/x-robots-noindex-a-folder-of-pdfs) and [Prevent XML sitemaps from showing up in Google search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/prevent-xml-sitemaps-from-showing-up-in-google-search-results).  You use the `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP header rather than a meta tag.     The HTTP header served with the txt file should look like:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

After implementing the HTTP header, remove the disallow from your `robots.txt`.  In order for crawlers to be able to see and honor the header, you need to make the txt files crawlable.

---

Under Apache web servers (most shared hosting), put the following code in the `.htaccess` file in the directory containing the .txt files:

```
<FilesMatch ".txt$">
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</FilesMatch>
```

---

If you are using nginx, your configuration would need to contain ([source](https://blogs.reliablepenguin.com/2014/06/24/set-x-robots-tag-header-plesknginx)):

```
location ~* ^/txtfiledir/.*\.txt$ {
  add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
}
```

---

If you are using IIS as your web server, the configuration would need to contain ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522348/add-custom-header-based-on-file-type)):

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Set custom HTTP response header">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Robots_Tag" pattern=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/txtfiledir/.*\.txt$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="noindex"/>
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is there something I'm missing in the question that implies the OP is using an Apache web server?

Comment: @DavidZ Well.. 'turns out it was a good guess : )

Comment: Apache is the most common web server, especially for beginner level shared hosting, so it is always a good guess.  I have added nginx and IIS configuration as well so that question will be useful to more people in the future.

Comment: Sure, and thanks for the edit. I just brought it up out of concern for people who don't use Apache and might be confused when they are told to look for a `.htaccess` file and don't find it; or more generally, whenever instructions for the most common version of a thing are presented as though they apply to _all_ versions of the thing.